# Merging 2 datasets in excel with the only common feature 2 date-colums (date deal announced and date deal completed)

Tags: excel, merge, vba

For a regression analysis in STATA i have received two separate Excel documents each including a variety of divestiture deals (and additional features).
The target-excel sheet (with control variables for STATA etc.) does not include any identifier for the divestiture deal (no Deal number, CUSIP, company name or anything to identify which companies undertook divestiture).It does include however, the deal announcement date and deal completion date.

The second sheet I got includes MORE deals than the first and the necessary identifiers. It also includes the 2 columns: Deal announcement date and deal completion date.

Now I need to somehow assign the identifier from the second excel file to the first file solely using the 2 columns about deal announcement/completion (because that is the only thing they have in common).

Does anyone here know how to do that in excel (fancy Vlookup ) or with a Macro?
I would be entirely grateful since I am talking about >5000 divestiture deals and don't think doing it manually will work.

Thank you all very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function Merger(a(), b()) 'a has all lines, b doesn't, **first column is SORTED**
Dim i1&, i2&, j&, output
ReDim sortie(1 To UBound(a), 1 To UBound(a, 2) + UBound(b, 2) - 1)
i1 = 1: i2 = 1
Do While i2 < UBound(b) And i1 < UBound(a)
    If a(i1, 1) = b(i2, 1) Then
        For j = 2 To UBound(b, 2)
            a(i1, UBound(a) + j - 1) = b(i2, j)
        Next
        i1 = i1 + 1
        i2 = i2 + 1
    ElseIf a(i1, 1) < b(i2, 1) Then
        i1 = i1 + 1
    Else
        Stop 'either not sorted or not present in a
    End If
Loop
Merger = output
End Function
```